# What's significant about this? (or where do you see this) ? 2^n-1

Tags: equation

I know this could be a vague question (or not!).

I've seen this somewhere 2^n-1 (or 2^n+1). Where do you see this equation? and why is it significant? And when do you use it?

Answer (score 3):

2^n-1 is the highest unsigned integer of n bits.

It's also a number easily tested for primeness, Mersenne prime http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

It's also the combination on my suitcase.

What's the point question?

Answer (score 0):

John Smith answered the most common use of it.  2^n-1 is the largest unsigned integer you can store with n bits.

- 8 bits:  255
- 16 bits: 65535
- 32 bits: 4294967295

Oh, and [mersenne primes](http://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/index.html) as Beemer pointed out (link from his page).

Comment: thank you. Now, what is the relationship between the fact that 2^n-1 is the largest unsigned integer in n bits and mersenne prime??

Answer (score 0):

It's also the maximum number of nodes in a balanced binary tree of height n.